# Fresh install Windows 10 and Ununtu 16.04 (or higher)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

With help from these forums, I have previously installed Ubuntu onto a PC that already had Windows installed. In this dual boot configuration I have to go into bios each time and select the boot drive, if I do nothing it will boot to windows.

I'm now in a position where I am doing a fresh build. Does this give me more options? Ideally I'd like to automatically be given a choice of which system to boot to and/or to boot to Ubuntu automatically if I do nothing.

Thanks

Baz

Comment: Is this a BIOS or an EFI machine?

Comment: On your old machine, did you do an `update-grub`? This is the usual way to have your computer present an up-to-date list of installed OSs at boot time. It should have been done automatically, but for some reason this has not worked.

Comment: The hardware is brand new and decent spec intel i5 on a ASRock - Z370 Extreme4 ATX LGA1151 Motherboard so I'm assuming it'll be an EFI machine but can't seem to verify this on line?

Comment: I think I chickened out of the update-grub in the old machine, I was just happy to get it working at that stage and  I know I had a new build coming in the not too distant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your question, its probably just a simple boot order problem.

When you install Ubuntu (or most other Linux systems) on an EFI machine, it will make a new entry in the /boot/efi partition. Usually, it will also change the boot order so Ubuntu's entry (GRUB) boots first, giving you the option of Linux or Windows. It sounds like Ubuntu simply didn't change the order for some reason. The fact that you are able to boot into Ubuntu from the BIOS indicates that it did successfully install this entry.

To fix this, you should be able to go into the BIOS setup, find the boot order option, and switch it so the "ubuntu" entry is first. You should get the grub menu after that.

BTW, you can find out for sure whether or not you are on an EFI machine by opening the run dialog on Windows, tying in "msinfo32", and looking for the entry that says "BIOS mode" under "System Summary". If it says "legacy", you are on BIOS; otherwise, you are on EFI.

If this doesn't answer your question, just comment. Good luck!